# URLClassLoader can't fulfill class load requests comming from new threads

Tags: java, classloader

**== Background ==**
I'm trying to implement auto-update feature for desktop java application, which is designed to use some sort of supervisor which can decide where to load application from (i.e. are we trying to load new version or we keep up with current). For that purpose I created bootstrapper which utilizes URLClassLoader.

**== Situation ==**
I have following artifacts:

- bootstrapper.jar
- app.jar
- lib/*.jar

**bootstrapper.jar** has it's own main() method, and MANIFEST file references entry point as

```
Main-Class: ru.skarpushin.projects.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper
```

So I can run that by invoking command line

```
javaw -jar bootsrapper.jar
```

**app.jar** this is main application (Spring-based application) with number of dependencies to 3rd party libs (located in lib folder) and referenced from manifest.mf

```
Class-Path: lib/balloontip-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar lib/commons-codec-1.6.ja
 r lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/fluent-
 hc-4.2.1.jar lib/gson-2.2.2.jar lib/guava-11.0.2.jar lib/log4j-1.2.16
 .jar lib/org.springframework.asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar lib/org.springfram
```

**lib/*.jar** - bunch of dependencies

**== The way I user classloaders is ==**

```
classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new File("app.jar").toURI().toURL() }, Thread.currentThread()
        .getContextClassLoader());
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
Class entryPointClass = classLoader.loadClass(entryPoint);
Method mainMethod = entryPointClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) args);
```

**== Problem ==**
That works perfectly for some classes and DOES NOT for other. Question is why and how to fix that?

It looks like it's somehow related to threads. 
Let's call Thread1 - the main thread when application starts and where I construct URLCalssLoader.
All requests to load classes on Thread1 fulfilled successfully regardless of their location (whether it's app.jar or from libs).
All requests to load classes on newly created threads (let's call them ThreadN) are failed .

Interesting thing I discovered is that:
- let's say ThreadN fails to load ClassA
- If I change code so that ClassA will be forced to load from Thread1 - then there will be no error on ThreadN
- I checked - context classloader of Thread1 and ThreadN - are the same

So it looks like on ThreadN I can use cached classes but cannot load new classes.

Any thoughts to fix that?

Comment: "I'm trying to implement auto-update feature for desktop java application" - I think java webstart is what you looking for?

Comment: I'm not at the point of options consideration and evaluation. WebStart is completely other story, my question is NOT related to it. But thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that was my code causing this behavior.

Bootstrapper.main() method was started; it opened URLClassLoader, loaded application entry point and invoked it. All that done in main thread. The thing is that this is desktop java application - and once main frame is shown then code is unblocked and bootstrapper.main method exited (while application is still being executed).

BUT in bootstrapper.main I did have finally clause where I explicitly call .close() method on URLClassLoader which forces it to use only cached classes and don't load new classes.

```
} finally {
    try {
        classLoader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // failed to close. don't care. Should we?
    }
}
```

Once I removed this code - issue is gone.